What is the cleanest way to re-implement Rust's BufRead, Read, and Seek traits for WASM?
I am working on a VScode extension, which uses a combination of Typescript and WebAssembly for file parsing and data handling. The parser is written in rust and compiled to WASM, as this is faster and far more memory efficient. While WASM does not support opening files directly, I am able to work around this by creating callback functions that call fs.read() via Typescript, and load in chunks of the file. The callbacks work, but I have run into some issues implementing this on the Rust Side of things, and I don't think I am handling all of the conditions I need to.
I should also mention that these files are potentially gigabytes in size, so it is not practical to statically load the file into memory as a Vec of bytes.
Here's what I have so far, but are there other functions I should implement? Or is there a simpler way to implement this that better leverages Rust's standard libraries? The only requirement is that when it does the actual reading of the file, it needs to call fsread() (which is defined by wit_bindgen) instead of whatever system call std::fs::File does, because that won't work with WASM.
struct WasmFileReader {
  fd: u32,
  file_size: u64,
  cursor: u64,
  buffer: Vec<u8>,
  buffer_index: u32,
  buffer_size: usize,
  read_callback: Arc<dyn Fn(u32, u64, u32) -> Vec<u8> + Send + Sync>,
}

impl WasmFileReader {
  fn new(fd: u32, buffer_size: usize) -> Self {
    let file_size = getsize(fd);
    let read_callback = Arc::new(|fd, cursor, size| {
      // Implement your callback logic here to read data from the file
      fsread(fd, cursor, size)
    });
    let mut reader = WasmFileReader { fd, file_size, cursor: 0, buffer: Vec::with_capacity(buffer_size), buffer_index: 0, buffer_size, read_callback };
    reader.fill_buf().unwrap();
    reader
  }
}

impl Read for WasmFileReader {
  fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> io::Result<usize> {
    log(&format!("Reading data from offset: {:?}, size: {:?}", self.cursor, buf.len()));
    let wasm_read_size = 49152;
    // First check to see if we have any data in the buffer
    let buffer_remaining = self.buffer_size - self.buffer_index as usize;
    let mut bytes_read = std::cmp::min(buf.len(), buffer_remaining);
    buf[0..bytes_read].copy_from_slice(&self.buffer[self.buffer_index as usize..self.buffer_index as usize + bytes_read]);
    self.consume(bytes_read);

    if buffer_remaining > 0 {
      return Ok(bytes_read);
    }

    let length = std::cmp::min(buf.len() as u32, self.file_size as u32 - self.cursor as u32) as usize;

    while bytes_read < length {
      let read_size = std::cmp::min(wasm_read_size, length - bytes_read);
      let data = (self.read_callback)(self.fd, self.cursor, read_size as u32);
      buf[bytes_read..bytes_read + data.len()].copy_from_slice(&data);
      bytes_read += data.len();
      self.cursor = std::cmp::min(self.cursor + data.len() as u64, self.file_size);
    }
    self.fill_buf()?;
    Ok(bytes_read)
  }


}

impl BufRead for WasmFileReader {
  fn fill_buf(&mut self) -> io::Result<&[u8]> {
    log(&format!("Filling buffer with data from offset: {:?}", self.cursor));
    if(self.cursor >= self.file_size) {return Ok(&[]);}
    let length = std::cmp::min(self.buffer_size as u64, self.file_size - self.cursor) as usize;
    self.buffer = (self.read_callback)(self.fd, self.cursor, length as u32);
    self.buffer_index = 0;
    Ok(&self.buffer[0..length])
  }

  fn consume(&mut self, amt: usize) {
    self.cursor += amt as u64;
    self.buffer_index += amt as u32;
  }
}

impl Seek for WasmFileReader {
  fn seek(&mut self, pos: SeekFrom) -> io::Result<u64> {
    log(&format!("Seeking to: {:?}", pos));
    let new_cursor;
    match pos {
      SeekFrom::Start(offset) => { new_cursor = offset; }
      SeekFrom::End(offset) => { new_cursor = (self.file_size as i64 + offset) as u64; }
      SeekFrom::Current(offset) => { new_cursor = (self.cursor as i64 + offset) as u64; }
    }
    if (new_cursor as i64) < 0 {
      self.cursor = 0;
      return Err(io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::InvalidInput, "Invalid seek to negative position"));
    }
    self.cursor = std::cmp::min(new_cursor, self.file_size);
    self.fill_buf()?;
    Ok(self.cursor)
  }
}
...

let file_reader: &'static mut WasmFileReader = unsafe { std::mem::transmute(file_reader) };



If you implement Read, you can get BufRead using BufReader. Note that this would match File which doesn't implement BufRead directly.

This worked! Thanks!
